# How to delete someone else's comments?

Tags: support, comments

Someone recently posted a self-answered question with one serious error and with several areas which could use improvement.  I posted a comment pointing these out, but did not DV - it was an otherwise ok attempt.  The OP contended there was no error, but eventually came to understand the issue with the serious error.

However, all the back and forth comments, including mine, which were **not** too chatty, spam or offensive just disappeared.  Now, I understand not wanting a series of comments which are critical of your answer to remain there forever, but how does someone delete/remove someone else's comments like that?

I've never seen that happen before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can flag comments that lead to the answer being improved as *obsolete*. A moderator will then remove those comments.

If there are many comments, you can flag the post itself and ask a moderator to clean up the comments; this is easier for a moderator as they can purge all comments with one action. If any comments are still worth preserving, the moderator can then undelete individual comments.

Comment: The thing is that they were not obsolete - true he fixed one thing but several other things worth noting still remain in the post.  I get it though - thanks!

Comment: @Plutonix: if the post was flagged for a clean-up the moderator would generally not try and make a call about what comments were perhaps not yet incorporated. You can always add a new comment.